# Spark repeated task requires driver memory

Tags: apache-spark, memory, driver

I do some repeated task in a spark application:

- I read snappy-compressed parquet file and filter on a date
- I compute some statistics

  ```
  dataFrame.filter(date=...)
    .groupyBy(date)
    .agg(sum(when(conditions, $"stat1")))
    .agg(...)
  ```
- I write the result to a CSV file

This is done about 100 times with different dates, at the same runtime. Each iteration can run with no problem, however with 4 Go driver memory it crashes to out of memory after 10 iteration, with 8 Go after 25 iterations. For each iteration, computations are done from the same dataframe object (ia. parquet is read only once).

I looks like something stays in the driver memory between each iteration. What can be the explanation?

Edit1: here is an example of csv reading.

```
spark.read
  .option("header", "true")        
  .csv(source)
  .select(myCols)
  .withColumnRenamed(...)
  .filter($"time" < ...)
  .repartition($"time")
  .write
  .option("compression", "snappy")
  .option("parquet.block.size", 32*1024*1024)
  .mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .partitionBy("time")
  .parquet(target)
```

Comment: Additional note: if I read the parquet again in each iteration, it crashes even faster, after 5 iteration.

Comment: After thinking about it, it looks like the driver keeps something from past executors or executions. As soon as there is a lot of work done in executors, it crashes. Is there such a configuration?

Comment: Can you show us the code how you load the data and how you store the csv file?

Comment: Edited my question with code example